# comparison of covariance matrices with unit that allows interpretation

Tags: covariance-matrix

I have fitted Gaussian distributions (3 dimensions) and need to compare their "variance".

I found that there are multiple approaches, such as

- The $\text{trace}(\Sigma)$ (which does not take into account the covariance between dimensions)
- $|\Sigma|$ (determinant)

However, I feel that neither $\sqrt{\text{trace}(\Sigma)}$ nor $\sqrt{|\Sigma|}$) even has the unit of my data.

So my question is: Is there a single-number that allows comparisons of the covariance matrices that are open to interpretation? For example "The average distances between two points of distribution A are 10 meters"?

Comment: There are too many questions here. Could you please edit your post down to only 1 question?

Comment: I rewrote the question to match the one of the title